# Unusual sorting of data - order by fixed data id

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am having a very unusual sorting issue. I have to arrange the items by pre-defined positions like what I have now in my database:

```
sid - auto increment
name - just something to distinguish varchar 100
sorting - this is where we define the exact position of the item
```

If we give `sorting = 2` to any product, it will be in the 2nd position no matter what. But it should be as defined by the sorting.

I can not arrange the items using `order by sorting desc` because most of the items are not assigned any position. Since some of the entries that have assigned values have `sorting = 0`, all the items with a sorting value not equal to zero should be placed before the other items, according to the plan.

This is the current code:

```
 <?php 
  $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","work");
   $getthedetails=mysqli_query($conn,"select sid,sorting,name from sorting order by sorting asc");
  while($thelistis=mysqli_fetch_array($getthedetails)){ ?>
  <div style="width:100px;font-weight:bold;color:#000;font-size:19px;font-   family:arial;height:100px;padding:49px;background:silver;float:left;margin:10px;">
    <?=$thelistis['sorting']?>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Ideally, I want sorting to be like 1,0,0,4,5,0,0,8.

What I want is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U85MN.png).

Comment: try `ORDER BY -sorting DESC`

Comment: @TerisL it will not work as i was using this till now. it will not work because sorting can have value=0 for non sorted item

Comment: column and table are both named "sorting"?

Comment: yes ... but it is not any issue i will be changing the table name this is just for the test purpose

Comment: don't know if it's possible through a query, i'll work on something and let you know with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below

```
$getthedetails=mysqli_query($conn,"select id,sorting,name from tbl_sorting order by sorting asc");
$arrayList = array();
while($thelistis=mysqli_fetch_array($getthedetails)){
    $arrayList[] = $thelistis;
}

foreach($arrayList as $key=>$list){
    if($list['sorting'] != 0){
        //Keep current element of array
        $temp = $arrayList[$key];
        //Make current element same as with the one to swap
        $arrayList[$key] = $arrayList[$list['sorting']-1];
        //Swap the kept one to its place
        $arrayList[$list['sorting']-1] = $temp;
    }
}


foreach($arrayList as $key=>$list){?>

<div style="width:100px;font-weight:bold;color:#000;font-size:19px;font-   family:arial;height:100px;padding:49px;background:silver;float:left;margin:10px;">
    <?php echo $list['sorting']?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello the answer is correct but when i use order by sorting desc it fails. what i want is that arrange the item with the pre defined value and if the value is blank then the last entered should come first..